# Spark hivecontext.sql - How does it create the number of partitions

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I perform the following:

```
val df = hiveContext.sql("select * from table")
df.show()
```

How does spark/hive choose the amount of partitions/tasks for it to run? When looking in the spark ui it appears to be a random amount depending on each table. Unfortunately when my data appears to be skewed, I get a really low amount of tasks say 30, when I want 1000. Thus taking forever.

Is there a way to explicitly define which column will be the partitioned key, is there a way to force it to evenly distribute the data to all of my nodes/executors?

I am running spark `1.5.1`.